# Geodesic Lines on GeoJSON features on google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geojson

Im writing a GeoJson layer for Google Maps that uses different kinds of Features, styled dynamically.

I cant find a way to plot `LineStrings` as geodesic lines.

I have to make a feature request for Google Maps API or I'm missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is now possible to style the line string to be geodesic.

```
map.data.setStyle(function(feature) {
  return {
    geodesic: true
  };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not implemented(currently), but it would be a desirable feature.

A workaround would be to hide the feature and create a custom polyline instead:

```
      map.data.addListener('addfeature', function(e) {
        //when it's a Line
        if(e.feature.getGeometry().getType()==='LineString'){
          //hide the feature
          map.data.overrideStyle(e.feature, {visible: false});
          //add a polyline
          new google.maps.Polyline({path    : e.feature.getGeometry().getArray(),
                                    map     : this.getMap(),
                                    geodesic: true});
        }
      });
```

It's a simple example, of course you also need to apply the styles & event-handlers

Answer (score 0):

Working from @Dr.Molle's answer, I am using `google.map.data.forEach()` as an alternative.

```
myMapInstance.map.data.addGeoJson(jsonData);
myMapInstance.map.data.forEach(function(feature) {
    if(feature.getGeometry().getType() === 'LineString') {
        myMapInstance.map.data.overrideStyle(feature, {visible: false});
        new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: feature.getGeometry().getArray(),
            map: myMapInstance.map,
            geodesic: true
        });
    }
});
```